# Eclipse plugin depenedency analysis in an automated manner

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, maven-2, osgi

I am in process to create a maven repository of a JAVA module which is part of Eclipse (probably OSGI). I am trying to get transitive dependencies of the JAR files I need using this way (http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace).

It use Plugin dependency analyser feature of the Eclipse to create a tree. I am wondering how does it work in background. I can find Imported namespace in manifest file of a JAR. But how does it find the relevent JAR file using that information?

My end goal is to export all these transitive depenedencies JAR and convert them to maven repository. I want to automate it ideally so I don't have to do it manually whenever there is an update.

Comment: That's what [Tycho](http://www.eclipse.org/tycho/) is for: a Maven plug-in that resolves dependencies and can build p2 repositories.

Comment: @howlger I want to do the opposite. Eclipse to maven

Comment: I still don't understand what and why you want to do exactly. If you want to export Eclipse plugins to a Maven repository so that they can be used as normal Maven dependency in a plain Java application, have a look at [JGit](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gerrit/jgit/jgit.git/tree) (-> [Maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit)).

Comment: @howlger I want to do the same for Jface/SWT. It doesn't already exist in mvn repository

Comment: I see. You could ask for it by reporting a bug to Platform SWT (see the [corresponding JGit bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=488114))

Comment: @howlger They have a tutorial to do it manually for JFace. I'm not sure if they care about automating it. http://wiki.eclipse.org/JFace. I also yesterday found another tool `jdeps`. I am going to try it today.

Answer (score 0):

In general Eclipse PDE projects have a *target* platform. This target platform holds the dependencies.

In OSGi bundles, the dependencies are specified in the manifest. There are *many* types of dependencies, the OSGi dependency model is magnitudes more powerful than the simplistic 'require' model of other module systems. Not only has it many types of dependencies (require bundle (the classic one), import package, require execution environment, require an implementation for an API, require a service, etc.) specified in *namespaces*, it also supports a powerful filter that is asserted on the properties of a *capability*. A capability is the opposite of a requirement.

To handle these capabilities and requirements, OSGi has a *resolver*. It takes a set of initial requirements and finds a solution where all requirements are satisfied and all the rules are followed. The result of the resolver is a set of *wires* that connect bundles together.

By far the best environment to play with this is bndtools. In bndtools you can use a P2 repository directly (Normally the target platform is a P2 repository). (You can also directly use a Maven repository or an OSGi standardized repository aka OBR.) In the bndtools bndrun file you can then select one or more root bundles of your graph. The resolver then calculates the set of bundles that are a *happy* closure. This is all done on GUI level.

There is also a command line called 'bnd' that you can install via brew or download its jar from https://bndtools.ci.cloudbees.com/job/bnd.master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/biz.aQute.bnd/generated/

That is a miraculous little tool that can do wonders but very badly documented although it does have a help command. :-( (I am the author)

Comment: Thanks. Who need documentation, when you have  author with you ;). I also found another tool jdeps yesterday. I am also going to try it today.